# Transaction failed after EHLO - Sendmail SMTP

Tags: php, smtp, sendmail

Do you know why i get `Transaction failed` in this negotiation:

```
CONNECTING TO mail.example.com
SUCCESS
220 ESMTP Sendmail 8.11.6/8.11.6; Thu, 14 Jul 2011 00:12:44 +0200
EHLO mail.example.com
554 Transaction failed.
```

is it something wrong with Sendmail or maybe there is some kind of protection based on IP address ?

server disconnects just after EHLO command.

Comment: Could it be trying to force a TLS handshake? What happens if you do a regular 'HELO' instead?

Comment: about the HELO - it's the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in improper line ending

Was: `EHLO mail.example.com\n`

Should be: `EHLO mail.example.com\r\n`